# What is 'service' method in HttpServlet class?

Tags: java, servlets

Below is a simple servlet written for learning.

```
package com.example.tutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello Java!");
    }

}
```

When a browser hits this URI: `http://localhost:8081/ServletsJSPExample/servletexample`,

By analyzing the request header of http packet, it shows `GET` request sent from the browser. But, In my servlet, I do not have `GET` request to process.

So,

When does `service` method gets invoked?

Why does `service` method receives this `GET` request?

Comment: `This is an HTTP-specific version of the Servlet.service method, which accepts HTTP specific parameters. This method is rarely overridden. Standard HTTP requests are supported by dispatching to Java methods specialized to implement them.` This is vague answer from javadoc

Comment: _This method is rarely overriden._ You're overriding it so what behavior do you expect and why? (This is the entry point of all Servlet handling.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`HttpServlet` implements `Servlet` whose [`service` method javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse) states

> Called by the servlet container to allow the servlet to respond to a
>   request.

This is the entry point of all Servlet handling. The Servlet container instantiates your `Servlet` class and invokes this method on the generated instance if it determines that your `Servlet` should handle a request.

`HttpServlet` is an `abstract` class which [implements](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java#HttpServlet.service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) this method by delegating to the appropriate `doGet`, `doPost`, `doXyz` methods, depending on the HTTP method used in the request.

```
@Override
public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    HttpServletRequest  request;
    HttpServletResponse response;

    if (!(req instanceof HttpServletRequest &&
            res instanceof HttpServletResponse)) {
        throw new ServletException("non-HTTP request or response");
    }

    request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    service(request, response);
}
[...]
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String method = req.getMethod();

    if (method.equals(METHOD_GET)) {
        long lastModified = getLastModified(req);
        if (lastModified == -1) {
            // servlet doesn't support if-modified-since, no reason
            // to go through further expensive logic
            doGet(req, resp);
        } else {
            long ifModifiedSince = req.getDateHeader(HEADER_IFMODSINCE);
            if (ifModifiedSince < lastModified) {
                // If the servlet mod time is later, call doGet()
                // Round down to the nearest second for a proper compare
                // A ifModifiedSince of -1 will always be less
                maybeSetLastModified(resp, lastModified);
                doGet(req, resp);
            } else {
                resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
            }
        }

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_HEAD)) {
        long lastModified = getLastModified(req);
        maybeSetLastModified(resp, lastModified);
        doHead(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_POST)) {
        doPost(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_PUT)) {
        doPut(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_DELETE)) {
        doDelete(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_OPTIONS)) {
        doOptions(req,resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_TRACE)) {
        doTrace(req,resp);

    } else {
        //
        // Note that this means NO servlet supports whatever
        // method was requested, anywhere on this server.
        //

        String errMsg = lStrings.getString("http.method_not_implemented");
        Object[] errArgs = new Object[1];
        errArgs[0] = method;
        errMsg = MessageFormat.format(errMsg, errArgs);

        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, errMsg);
    }
}
```

If you override the `service` method from `HttpServlet`, you lose that behavior and revert back to a single handling of all Servlet requests.